# авторизация на сайте через requests

Tags: python, сессия, requests

Пытаюсь войти в личный кабинет используя requests.Session на сайте "https://www.pythonanywhere.com (чтобы выкачать данные с другого проекта):

```
login = 'пользователь'
password = 'пароль'
response = requests.get('https://www.pythonanywhere.com/login/').text
token = re.findall(r"name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='(.*)' />", response)
data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token[0],
        'login_view-current_step': 'auth',
        'auth-username': login,
        'auth-password': password,
        }
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post("https://www.pythonanywhere.com/login/",
           data=data)
    r = s.get('https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/пользователь')
    r.text
```

однако не получается войти на сайт и выдается страница для ввода логина пароля

Comment: Потому что `csrfmiddlewaretoken` динамический. Его нужно парсить

Comment: вы правы, он динамический, но все равно не получилось авторизироваться:response = requests.get('https://www.pythonanywhere.com/login/').text
    token = re.findall(r"name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='(.*)' />", response)
    data = {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': token[0],
            'login_view-current_step': 'auth',
            'auth-username': login,
            'auth-password': password,
            }
    with requests.Session() as s:
        s.post("https://www.pythonanywhere.com/login/",
               data=data)
        r = s.get('https://www.pythonanywhere.com/user/username/')

Comment: код в вопрос будьте добры

Comment: Есть пример авторизации на pythonanywhere: https://github.com/kranonetka/PyScripts/tree/master/pythonanywhere%20extender.

Comment: попробовал его способом (собственно они похожи, только он еще получает новый токен с авторизированной страницы), не получалось, так как все равно s.get(url), перенаправляет на  неавторизированную страницу